# How can I change the Managed By to a single user in multiple groups using a csv

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

How can I change the "Managed By" name in a Security Group in AD to a single user in multiple groups using a csv in powershell?

Comment: What have you tried? How does your csv look? ......

Comment: I originally tried to include it in the script when I created the groups but it failed. I finally ran a successful script to create the groups but forgot to add the managed by in the script. Now I want to add the name of the managed by to all of the groups. I also from time to time need to change this on multiple groups and would like a script that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest something like this:

```
$manager = Get-ADUser -Identity "USERNAME"

Import-Csv groups.csv | ForEach-Object {
    Set-ADGroup -Identity $_.Group -ManagedBy ($manager.DistinguishedName)
}
```

You can even skip the `Get-ADUser` part and just do:

```
Import-Csv groups.csv | ForEach-Object {
    Set-ADGroup -Identity $_.Group -ManagedBy "USERNAME"
}
```

Comment: I used:

Import-Csv D:\Scripts\groups.csv | ForEach-Object {
    Set-ADGroup -Identity $_.Group -ManagedBy "TEKE001"
}

Comment: And I get this error:

Set-ADGroup : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Supply a non-null argument and try the command 
again.
At D:\Scripts\ManByChange.ps1:2 char:27
+     Set-ADGroup -Identity $_.Group -ManagedBy "TEKE001"
+                           ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-ADGroup], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADGroup

Comment: You need to replace "Group" with whatever property you have. You didn't provide a csv sample so I had to guess.

Comment: My header in csv is GroupName. so change "-Identity $_.Group" to "-Identity $_.GroupName"?